# How to Populate Yes/No Checkbox List Using Values from GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a checkbox list in a grid view edit popup with yes and no choices. I am attempting to populate the checkboxlist with data from the database in the form of "Yes" and "No" strings. How can I select Yes or No on the checkbox list so the user can view and edit the data?

I am using a checkbox list rather than radio buttons because the user needs to be able to deselect all checkboxes.

ASPX:

```
            <asp:CheckBoxList ID="cblCLECompleted" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" cssclass="cbTableRow" AutoPostBack="false" Width="50">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Yes" Value="Yes">
                </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="No" Value="No">                     
                </asp:ListItem>
            </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Code Behind:

```
    private void PopulateAttorneyPopup(int rowIndex)
    {
        GridViewRow row = gvAttorneys.Rows[rowIndex];
        txtAttorneyName.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
        txtStartDate.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
        if (row.Cells[3].Text == "Yes")
        {
            cblCLECompleted.Selected = "Yes";
        }
        else
        {
            cblCLECompleted.Selected = "No";
        }
        txtLast4ofSS.Text = row.Cells[4].Text;
    }
```

Thanks for your time and assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue at the same time I submitted the question. I guess asking it made the light bulb come on. I didn't know I could use SelectedValue and that's apparently what I needed to use. I also simplified the statement.

```
    private void PopulateAttorneyPopup(int rowIndex)
    {
        GridViewRow row = gvAttorneys.Rows[rowIndex];
        txtAttorneyName.Text = row.Cells[1].Text;
        txtStartDate.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
        cblCLECompleted.SelectedValue = (row.Cells[3].Text == "Yes") ? "Yes" : "No";
        txtLast4ofSS.Text = row.Cells[4].Text;
    }
```